# Placing the errors in its respective div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-4

Here i am getting my Error Messages from a separate page and i am displaying it in a a div called `#stage_error`

```
$('#stage_error').html(error_string);
```

So, the errors will be displayed like this

```
The bus no field is required.
The comp id field is required.
The total seats field is required.
```

But what i want is to display the errors in its respective div's

i.e., the Bus no should be displayed near the div <`div id='busno'>` like this.

How can i do that ?

**Json :**

```
{"busno":["Bus No field is required"],"Comp Id":["Comp Id is required."]}
```

### Update :

**Script for request and showing error :**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#driver").click(function(event) {
            var BusNo = $("#BusNo").val();
            var CompID = $("#CompID").val();
            var TotalSeats = $("#TotalSeats").val();
            var _token = $("#_token").val();
            $.post("managebus_register", {
                _token: _token,
                BusNo: BusNo,
                CompID: CompID,
                TotalSeats: TotalSeats
            },

            function(data) {
                if (data != '') {
                    obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    var error_string = '';
                    $.each(obj, function(entry) {
                        error_string += obj[entry] + '<br/>';
                    });

                    $('#stage_error').html(error_string);

                } else {

                    $('#stage_success').text('Resistered Succesfully');
                    $("#stage_error").hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Laravel Controller :**

```
public function managebusregister()
    {   
        $BusNo = Input::get('BusNo');
        $CompID = Input::get('CompID');
        $TotalSeats = Input::get('TotalSeats');
        $data  =  Input::except(array('_token')) ;
        $rule  =  array(
                    'BusNo' => 'required|unique:company_bus',
                    'CompID' => 'required',
                    'TotalSeats' => 'required|max:50'
                        ) ;
        $validator = Validator::make($data,$rule);
        if ($validator->fails())
            {   
                $messages = $validator->messages();
                return json_encode($validator->messages());  //php encoded value
             }
        else
            {
            DB::insert('insert into company_bus (BusNo, CompID, TotalSeats) values (?, ?, ?)',
                                    array($BusNo, $CompID, $TotalSeats));       
            return '';
             }

        }
```

Html Code :

```
<div id="stage_error" style="color:red;font-size:15px"></div>
<div id="stage_success" style="color:green;font-size:20px"></div>
```

and beyond that i have each field input boxes,

```
<input type="text" id="BusNo" name="BusNo"/>
<input type="text" id="CompID" name="CompID"/>
```

How can i throw error messages near the respective fields

Comment: please share some relevant html and script that you have tried so far.

Comment: Give the feeling that you have `HTML` empty inputs with attribute 'required'

Comment: @oscarvady: No i have updated the Question. Kindly find it.

Comment: show us your json so that can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the approach: Observe I've added spans with error after text boxes.

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .error { color:red; font-size:15px; }
</style>
```

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="BusNo" name="BusNo" /><span class="error"></span>

<input type="text" id="CompID" name="CompID" /><span class="error"></span>
```

**JavaScript** I did some changes as per the jQuery standard, it should work well, if you're not interested then you can ignore all the changes but can take only below mentioned `if` logic block.

The error display added in `if (!data) {...}`

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#driver", function (event) {
        var BusNo = $("#BusNo").val(),
            CompID = $("#CompID").val(),
            TotalSeats = $("#TotalSeats").val(),
            _token = $("#_token").val();
        $.post("managebus_register", {
            _token: _token,
            BusNo: BusNo,
            CompID: CompID,
            TotalSeats: TotalSeats
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("span.error").empty();//All previous error messages cleared here.
            if (!data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                //obj = {"busno":["Bus No field is required"],"Comp Id":["Comp Id is required."]}
                $.each(obj, function (entry) {
                    var targetSelector='';
                    if (entry == "busno") {
                        targetSelector = "#BusNo";
                    }
                    if (entry == "Comp Id") {
                        targetSelector = "#CompID";
                    }
                    if(targetSelector) //Here we're setting error message for respective field
                        $(targetSelector).next("span.error").html(obj[entry]);
                });
            } else {
                $('#stage_success').text('Resistered Succesfully');
                $("#stage_error").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hey its working great, sorry for late response , but it works great !! thanks\

Comment: Can i do this ??  if(!targetSelector)
    {
        $("span.error").text('');
    }

Comment: You need to look into the response data that you've received from server. I think you didn't understand my solution to your issue. Here I'm explaining: In done function, if you see this line `$("span.error").empty();//All previous error messages cleared here.`, it will do the job to clear all error messages at very first. Then if response error data obj exists, it will process each field error message in the `$.each(obj,function(entry){...});`. in the function if it found  the field id as entry key then the error message will be added to next span tag of field.

Comment: I've added only comments, no change in code, I'm glad that you understand now and it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:

```
 var json = JSON.parse('{"busno":["Bus No field is required"],"Comp Id":["Comp Id is required."]}');
  //  alert(json['busno']);

    $("#busno").html(json.busno);// like this for others also.
```

**change here:**

```
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    var error_string = '';
                    $.each(obj, function(entry) {
                        error_string += obj[entry] + '<br/>';

       if(entry == 'busno'){
                   $("#busno").html(obj[entry]);// like this for others also.
                  }


if(entry == 'Comp Id'){
                   $("#compid").html(obj[entry]);// like this for others also.
                  }
                    });

                    $('#stage_error').html(error_string);
```

Comment: Actually i am getting json from external page, Only modifying json is the way ?

Comment: and may i do  else
    {
        $("span.error").text('');
    } if it succeeds the condition ?

Comment: do not add this else with single if make if(entry == 'busno'){}else if(entry == 'Comp Id')else {// your part here}

Comment: and use $("span.error").html(''); instead of what you have written.

Comment: Sorry, even if i like that, i am facing for issues,

Comment: i mean, once the once suceeds it is not showing the empty html

Comment: you mean to clear messages isn't it. then  $(".error").html(''); should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64610/discussion-between-biz-dev-and-suchit).